# ReactJS with TypeScript 1.7

Tags: reactjs, typescript1.6

I follow ReactSample using JavaScript

[image]

It can run right the result is

[image]

But When I change the js to TypeScript like this

[image]

It not give wrong result like this

[image]

I think all is right . I can compile it with tsc --jsx react  -target ES6 . I don't know why it can not get result in the html page ? Can you help me

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code, not images of your code. Images force would-be answerers to manually retype your code in order to suggest corrections, which is a big disincentive to quality answers.

Comment: In the second example you assign `this.state` directly instead of using `setState` in `componentDidMount`